# Same data set - More rows with less columns or Less rows with more columns

Tags: database, database-design, mariadb

Database - MariaDB

The requirement is to store end of day closing balance for different customer for different accounts types (around 15 account types)

**Approach 1 (50 Million rows X 10 Columns)**

Name | Date | Amount | Account

A    | 1 Jan| 100    | Saving

A    | 1 Jan| 200    | Current

B    | 1 Jan| 300    | Saving

**Approach 2 (10 Million rows x 25 columns)**

Name | Date | Saving | Current

A    | 1 Jan| 100    | 200

B    | 1 Jan| 300    | 0

Index will be on Name Date for both tables.

Approach 1 will have index on Account column as well

**Query**

Each query will have where clause on Name and Date

Answer (score 1):

The size difference between the two designs is within an order of magnitude, and really within a fairly small factor.  Size aside, the first design is probably more desirable for several reasons.

First, if you at some later point need to support a third or fourth account type, you can simply keep adding new rows with the same table structure.  On the other hand, adding support for a new account type to the second design requires changing the structure of the table.

From a reporting point of view, it is probably advantageous to have the account type as a single separate column.  This makes aggregation and filter queries easy to write, and with the right index, these queries can be made fast.  The second design forces you to hardwire your queries to separate columns for each account type.  This can end up being debt later on should the table design need to change.

Comment: Thanks Tim Biegeleisen, I understand from storage perspective Approach 1 is better. The final report that user want looks same as the Approach 2 where each account are in separate columns. Of course when querying the data from Approach 1, we can add case statements like 'case account='Saving' then amount as Saving as so on'

Comment: @michael Not sure if you are asking for a follow-up comment, but yes, you have answered the reporting question yourself, and conditional aggregation can be used to generate the output you see in the second version.  I guess it's a trade off.